# Spacing after text without padding/margin

Tags: css, html

I looking-for how to add spacing after text in paragraph.

HTML:

```
<h1>abc</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    float: left;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    text-indent: 15px;
}

h1:after {
    content: '';
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

But :after work only in modern browser?
How to add space after text without padding and margin for older browser?

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YS2MQ/1/

Comment: Why can't you use margins?

Comment: `word-spacing` might work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YS2MQ/2/ - for those who live in 1994 :)

Comment: Are you trying to add space within the red box? Why without padding?

Comment: Padding increases width...

Comment: What are the cases where the width should not increase?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider adding the `&nbsp;` entity to the html.

Answer (score 0):

Use padding:

```
h1 {
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: OP wrote "without padding and margin"

Comment: There seems to be a lot of complication and extra markup being proposed when simple padding would do. OP doesn't explain his/her requirements why simple padding is inadequate. If it is desired to *always* have space before and after the test, then I don't see how width is increasing. If the extra space is only desired under some circumstances, those circumstances are not explained. Usually the simple solution is best.

Answer (score 0):

A few methods I can think of are in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YS2MQ/3/ and I added a completely different workaround at the end of this answer.

**HTML:**

```
<h1 class="ie8plus">abc</h1>

<h1 class="border">abc</h1>

<h1 class="cc">abc<!--[if lte IE 7]> <span>I'm IE7-, let me die please</span><![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> not IE7- here<!--<![endif]--></h1>

<h1 class="textindent"><span>abc</span></h1>

<h1>.after<span class="after"> </span></h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    text-indent: 15px;
}

.ie8plus:after {
    content: '';
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.border {
    border-right: 20px solid blue; /* you want red obviously. 'transparent' won't work in IE7- so you must have a solid background under h1 */
}
.textindent {
    text-indent: 35px; /* already 15px and we add 20px */
}
.textindent span {
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
}
.cc span { /* HTML conditional content only interpreted by IE7-. Messy on so many levels... Let's keep the use of conditional comments to conditional stylesheets and conditional classes! */
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}
h1 .after {
    display: inline; zoom: 1; /* that's inline-block for IE7-... and inline isn't required as span is already inline */
    width: 20px;
    height: 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: darkred;
}
```

**In words:**

- You can add a right border,
- you can abuse conditional comments to force IE7- to see HTML content that other browsers won't see (beware: use it more than once per page and it'll be unmanageable),
- you can enclose text into a `span` and play with `text-indent` and relative positioning,
- you can add an empty `span.after` to mimick the pseudo `:after (I left a space in my fiddle but I don't think it's necessary). Yes it's extra-code and *blah blah blah* BUT if you're forced into supporting old browsers with constraints and methods they don't support, well there are not many options left! ;)

**Or:**

I see in one of your comment that you've a constraint with `width`. Your problem would be solved with the use of the CSS property **[box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing)** (with appropriate vendor prefixes) where padding and borders can be taken into account of the whole width, not added anymore:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box }
```

but that's only supported by IE8+. That's the default behavior of IE7-... without doctype. *Oh the irony!*
But all isn't lost, there exists a polyfill: **[boxsizing.htc](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill)**

Answer (score 0):

[It's the whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)(in this case, a line break) between your two canvas

Alternatively, you can keep your whitespace, and add float: left to canvas in your CSS. If you

[clear your floats.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)